# Filtering out strings from an array of strings in Matlab using regexp

Tags: regex, string, matlab

**Is there an equivalent function to strmatch that returns the numeric index of all array elements that begin with the specified regular expression (instead of string ?**

Background: I've got an array of strings called `strarray`. I want to filter out all the strings that do NOT have a specific `strprefix`. The following code that looks for indexes of an array of strings ([strmatch func](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/strmatch.html)) for which a particular prefix exists, and then builds new array from the lines that contain the prefix:

```
indexes = [];
n = strmatch(strprefix, strarray);
indexes = [indexes,n];
indexes = sort(indexes);
newarray = strarray(indexes);
```

It works OK, however the `prefix` is a string and I'd like to use defined regular expression instead.

**Or perhaps there's an easier way (one liner?) to do such task ?**

---

Update

I am aware of the regexp function. I am trying to filter out strings from an array of string, but I struggle to do it in one or two steps. My current code to do this (not sure if it's the correct Matlab way of coding).

- Step 1. Empty the string with no prefix: `regexp(strarray,[prefix,'.*'],'match','once');`
- Step 2. Get index of empty lines `emptyCells = cellfun(@isempty,array);`
- Step 3. Remove the empty rows `array(emptyCells) = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really solved your problem yourself, but here is how you would do everything you say in a single (long) line. Note - I am assuming your `prefix` string starts with `^` so it properly matches "the start of the string" (if indeed that is what you want to do). Other question - unless all strings in strarray are the same length, you really should be using a cell array. In which case your Step 3 doesn't remove the string, it just sets it to `[]`. I therefore suggest changing the logic so you "include all the good strings" in your output, rather than deleting the bad ones. That makes it look as follows:

```
strippedArray = strarray(~cellfun('isempty',regexp(strarray,[prefix,'.*'],'match','once')));
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

The function [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) allows you to match strings using regular expressions.

If you need help constructing or applying your regular expression, you may want to post additional detail.